# Ambiguous function call error is thrown when i used overloaded functions differentiated by unsigned int and unsigned long ?Is this overloading valid

Tags: c++

I have 2 functions as shown below

```
void GetValue(unsigned int){}
void GetValue(unsigned long){}
```

If i make a call GetValue(4294967296) i get the following error "Ambiguous function call".
Since both int and long have size of 4 bytes will this overloading work?

Comment: umm, no, if you get an error message.

Comment: How are you expecting the compiler to know which one to call? Your constant is neither an `unsigned int` nor an `unsigned long`, so they both match equally well (or equally badly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Overloading is valid, but here you have one type conversion from signed value to unsigned in both cases. Therefore compiler can't chose between two. Threfore your program doesn't compile.
2. You can't make him chose between to on 32bit systems where sizeof(int)=sizeof(long)=4 bytes, unless you use explicit type casting `GetValue((unsigned int)4294967696);`. Literals specifications are same for `int` and `long` types `u` or `U`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal
3. But you can make compiler chose if you have different sizes of int and long (which can be a case on 64 bit system). In this case compiler chose according to the range of the variable.

   So you can make it compile, if you give an unsigned literal:

   ```
   GetValue(4294967696u);
   ```

   4294967296 is out of range for int, which is 0..4,294,967,295 for 4 byte long unsigned int. And in range for 8 bytes long unsigned long. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(v=vs.90).aspx ) Threfore the program will call the long-function.

This program does compile and chose different functions according to the range of the literals:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void GetValue(unsigned int x){cout << "int  " << x << endl;}
void GetValue(unsigned long x){cout << "long " << x << endl;}

int main() {
  GetValue(4294967295u);
  GetValue(4294967696u);
  GetValue(static_cast<unsigned int>(4294967696));

  cout << sizeof( unsigned int ) << " " << sizeof( unsigned long ) << endl;
}
```

with the output with gcc on 64-bit system:

```
int  4294967295
long 4294967696
int  400
4 8
```

Comment: Why is the third one `400`?

Comment: @ColeJohnson, because 4294967696 is out of range for unsigned int (which is 0..4,294,967,295), so it is cut off during type conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Just cast type of your call, ex. GetValue((unsigned int)4294967296)